# REST API Basic Authentication security

Tags: basic-authentication, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm writing an application that use woocommerce REST API with Basic authentication.     In each request I should add a username and password in base64 encoding. However, each authentication header can i preview in the browser, decode and execute requests from another place which I would not like, of course.

Did I configure apps incorrectly? 
I do not understand how it would be safe, since everyone can get the keys from the header.
How to configure this connection correctly? 
Maybe should I use JWT auth?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce-rest-api IS NOT frondend rest api. To be able to use this on the front should be properly adapted ACL. [This help me understand](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/17983)